# Gitlabhq - unable to push to new repository

Tags: git

I have just setup a ubuntu server with gitlabhq, added a user with a key and a new repository.

When I try to push I get:

Permission denied, please try again.
  Permission denied, please try again.
  Permission denied (publickey,password).
  fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

I cant see any errors in any of my logs though.
Also I have added my local machines public key to the authorized_keys on the server.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is the public key either password-less or unlocked via ssh-agent? IIRC git push does not support asking for passphrase.
2. Try ssh-ing manually.
3. Try `GIT_SSH='ssh -v' git push ...` to get more verbose output from ssh.
4. [EDIT] Check, that the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file and all it's parent directories down to root have permissions 755 (that is must *not* be group writable) or stricter. Home and below also should be owned by the user and the above have to be owned by root. Otherwise ssh will refuse to read `authorized_keys`.

Comment: I get a password prompt. I have checked the authorised key and the keys permissions is there anything else ?

Comment: @Alex: Are you getting a "password" prompt because public key authentication failed or a "passphrase" prompt because the key is locked?

Comment: @Alex: Than try `ssh -v -v -v` and try looking at the logs on the server. Ssh usually logs into `/var/log/auth.log`. One more thing; check permissions to the directories on the server. Ssh is picky about permissions.